# Dividir lista en lista de listas

Tags: python

Tengo una lista y quiero dividirla en una lista de listas cada 3 valores.

```
lista = ['131997','https://www.google.com.ar/','google.com.ar','134930','https://www.a-a.com/','a-a.com']
```

lo que busco es exactamente esto:

```
lista = [['131997','https://www.google.com.ar/','google.com.ar'],['134930','https://www.a-a.com/','a-a.com']]
```

Answer (score 4):

Con este código podrías hacerlo, asumiendo que la lista original tiene N elementos y N es múltiplo de 3:

```
lista = ['131997','https://www.google.com.ar/','google.com.ar','134930','https://www.a-a.com/','a-a.com']

lista_nueva = []
for i in range(0, len(lista), 3):
    lista_nueva.append(lista[i:i+3])
print(lista_nueva)
```

Answer (score 1):

Una forma super compacta mediante comprensión de listas es la siguiente:

```
nueva_lista = [lista[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(lista), 3)]
```

Hacemos uso de un funcionalidad del parámetro opcional `step` de [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#func-range) que nos permite retornar rangos en pasos, en este caso de 3. Luego simplemente vamos haciendo un `slice`de la lista: `lista[i:i+3]` por cada índice + 3.